# How to get PDF of another MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, rotativa

I'm trying to achieve the following:

User will submit a form and be redirected to the thank you page. In the thank you page load, user's "marks-list" (`MarksList.cshtml`) has to be converted to pdf and then emailed (all happening in background).

I have tried `Rotativa` following this [article](http://www.intstrings.com/ramivemula/articles/export-asp-net-mvc-view-to-pdf-in-3-quick-steps/). But it explains how to  load the other view as PDF. In my case, I don't need to view it. Just convert it run time, so that it can be emailed as an attachment.

Is this possible with Rotativa. If not, are there any alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

I have never use *Rotativa* but I used [SelectPdf](https://selectpdf.com/community-edition/) and I highly recommend to you (Community Edition).

It's really easy to use and configurable.

That's the sample code from their site. you can also find a lot of demo about it.

```
// instantiate the html to pdf converter
HtmlToPdf converter = new HtmlToPdf();

// convert the url to pdf
PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertUrl(url);

// save pdf document
doc.Save(file);

// close pdf document
doc.Close();
```

This is also a great [example](http://www.intstrings.com/ramivemula/articles/convert-an-asp-net-mvc-webpage-html-to-pdf/) for the beginning.

Comment: Thank you. In my case marks-list are unique and the view will be populated by its related model. Can this still work

Comment: I think yes. you can create httpClient then send a request to the action after that you can get all htmlString then you can convert like **converter.ConvertHtmlString(htmlString, baseAddress.ToString());**
please check the blog page. its really useful. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

you can use bytescout to simplify your work :

```
using (HtmlToPdfConverter converter = new HtmlToPdfConverter())
            {
                converter.PageSize = PaperKind.A4;
                converter.Orientation = PaperOrientation.Portrait;
                converter.Footer = "<p style=\"color: blue;\">FOOTER TEXT</p>";

                converter.ConvertHtmlToPdf("sample.html", "result.pdf");

                // You can also pass a link instead of the input file:  
                //converter.ConvertHtmlToPdf("http://google.com", "result.pdf");
            }

            // Open result file in default PDF viewer
            Process.Start("result.pdf");
```